# cx_freeze / pptx "PackageNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-2.7, powerpoint, cx-freeze

I'm working on a Python-programm that use the modul "pptx" (edit and manipulate powerpoint). The programm works without problem in the interpretor, but once I start it as a .exe file (built with cx_freeze or py2exe) I have this error-message when I click on the main-button :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1470, in __call__
File "pptx_02.py", line 187, in ButtonErstellen
File "pptx\api.pyc", line 29, in __init__
File "pptx\presentation.pyc", line 87, in __init__
File "pptx\presentation.pyc", line 170, in __open
File "pptx\packaging.pyc", line 88, in open
File "pptx\packaging.pyc", line 671, in __new__
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'C:\Users\Moi\Programmation\Python\build\exe.win32-2.7\library.zip\pptx\templates\default.pptx'
```

The problem is that the file "default.pptx" actually exists at this adress.

While looking in the functions of "pptx", I may had an idea about the reason of this problem (but no idea of the solution). 
For the last error : File "pptx\packaging.pyc", line 671, in **new**
is the following code:

```
class FileSystem(object):
    """
    Factory for filesystem interface instances.

    A FileSystem object provides access to on-disk package items via their URI
    (e.g. ``/_rels/.rels`` or ``/ppt/presentation.xml``). This allows parts to
    be accessed directly by part name, which for a part is identical to its
    item URI. The complexities of translating URIs into file paths or zip item
    names, and file and zip file access specifics are all hidden by the
    filesystem class. |FileSystem| acts as the Factory, returning the
    appropriate concrete filesystem class depending on what it finds at *path*.
    """
    def __new__(cls, file):
        # if *file* is a string, treat it as a path
        if isinstance(file, basestring):
            path = file
            if is_zipfile(path):
                fs = ZipFileSystem(path)
            elif os.path.isdir(path):
                fs = DirectoryFileSystem(path)
            else:
                raise PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % path)
        else:
            fs = ZipFileSystem(file)
        return fs
```

The problem may be that the final file (default.pptx) isnot a zip but is in a zip. But I have no idea how I could fix it or if it realy is the problem.

If somebody as an idea ...

Thank you !

Comment: I think you're right about the problem. pptx doesn't expect to find itself inside a zip file. You'll need to modify it so it can load its template somehow. Looking at `Presentation.__default_pptx_path` might be a good starting point.

Comment: I added the library "pptx" in "includefiles" and in "package" in my setup.py and it finally worked.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: The solution was found by Tyrtamos (http://python.jpvweb.com/mesrecettespython/doku.php)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how, but I'm glad you fixed it ;-)